# menu doesn't show in different languages

Tags: menus, multi-language

I have a custom menu on a site with multiple languages (WPML plugin) 
The menu is not being displayed in any languages other than native.

1. Can the menu be translated?
2. Can the menu be shown in all languages without any change to the text? (when it's mostly names that shouldn't be translated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the menu can be translated, and, yes, it will be shown in all languages.

Does your menu use the WordPress 3 menu feature? If yes, the video here explains how to setup the translation: http://wpml.org/2010/07/wpml-1-8-0-with-multilingual-menus/